# Function in Excel to return #VALUE

Tags: excel

The Excel function `=Na()` returns `#N/A`.

Is there an equivalent function that returns `#VALUE`?

Obviously you could do something like `=1*""` but is there something more satisfactory?

Comment: You could write a VBA routine:  `Public Function ValueError() As Variant: ValueError = CVErr(xlErrValue): End Function`  A bit overkill though. :)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really... but you can just use **VALUE()** as below

```
=VALUE("")
```